# Suitescript - cannot update Sales Team - salesrep

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am a newbie to scripting.   I am running this SuiteScript on Leads - we have web leads coming in with a Sales rep coming in on a field called "custentityonlineleadsalesrep".   I have this running on create only - any ideas??

if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE)
                   return;

```
    var record = context.newRecord;                                             
    var webrep = record.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'custentityonlineleadsalesrep',                        
                })

    record.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'salesteam',
                fieldId: 'employee',
                line: 1,
                value: webrep
                });
    record.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'salesteam',
                fieldId: 'salesrole',
                line: 1,
                value: '-2'
                });
    record.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'salesteam',
                fieldId: 'isprimary',
                line: 1,
                value: 'T'
                });
    record.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'salesteam',
                fieldId: 'contribution',
                line: 1,
                value: '100%'
                });
    }
```

Comment: Did that answer help you, at all?  Do you have more questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you seeing any errors?  Are you logging any of the activity (such as what value is actually in the webrep variable?  Try adding a:

```
log.debug({title:'webRep',details:webrep});
```

line after you declare and set that variable, just to ensure that the expected value is in the variable.

Try changing the line to 0 (SuiteScript 2.0 starts at 0 not one).

Also, every time I've tried to set sublist lines like that, it has failed.  If the above does not work try selecting the line you want, writing to it, then committing it. something like this:

```
record.selectLine({sublistId:'salesteam',line:0});
record.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:'salesteam',fieldId:'employee',value:webrep,line:0});
record.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:'salesteam',fieldId:'salesrole',value:-2,line:0});
record.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:'salesteam',fieldId:'isprimary',value:true,line:0});
record.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:'salesteam',fieldId:'contribution',value:'100%',line:0});
record.commitLine({sublistId:'salesteam'});
```

Hope that helps...